# One face for multiple accounts in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-hello

How do I setup Windows 10 so that I can use my face to login to at least two Windows accounts? I tried to register my face for a different account, but I get the following error:

> Sorry, something went wrong It looks like you've already set up Windows Hello on another account. Remove face recognition from your other account, and then try again.

It would be nice to be able to use the same face to login to another account, as this would be convenient for a person with multiple Windows accounts.

Is there a workaround for this limitation?

Comment: Ouch - that's what I'd call a serious security issue. Nothing, nothing outside of that one account should be able to tell what 'face' is associated with what ID. That's security 101.

Comment: You won’t be able to since Windows hello, is going to use your face, to determine which account to log you into.

Comment: Does windows store the face ID outside the computer? That's a terrible idea, one I shall be glad to never adopt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround I found was to use my hands as goggles on my face for my other Windows account. It's not perfect though as Windows Hello sometimes cannot recognize my face.